# Lip Trilling on Lower Notes

Tags: jazz, trombone

I am playing "One Mint Julep" in my jazz band (trombone 4 part). I have a G3 note with a short lip trill. I usually see lip trills on higher notes, so what is a proficient way to play these? My band instructor said to just move my slide from 4th to 3rd position very quickly, but was wondering if there were any ways I can do a lip trill normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playing the G in 6th position with the F-trigger might give you an easier lip trill.
If that doesn't work and you don't want to use the 3rd position G, then you have to find a way to fake it. Your band director's suggestion sounds like a good way to do that. Or maybe you can get away with just leaving the trill out.

Answer (score 0):

Are we talking about the bit at 2'30" in the Louis Prima version?  Stay in 4th and lip trill up to a (rather flat) B.   Think 'shake' rather than 'trill'.

Comment: We are playing the version by Rudy Toombs.

Comment: Yes, Rudy Toombs wrote the song, original recording was by The Clovers.  Is an arranger mentioned on your big band version?

https://dailymusicbreak.com/2018/03/12/the-clovers-one-mint-julep/

Comment: The arranger is Alan Baylock.